# Network interface statistics: tx_dropped value always 0

Tags: ifconfig, statistics

I am writing a program that collects and displays network interface metrics located in the `/sys/class/net/` folder.

When I was reading about the meaning of `rx_dropped` value, I came to the conclusion that this value as many possible causes, such as the ones specified in the first answer of this post:

[ifconfig eth0 RX dropped packets](https://serverfault.com/questions/528290/ifconfig-eth0-rx-dropped-packets)

However, I cannot find any information on the `tx_dropped` value. I first though it would be related to TCP segments sent that did not get an Aknowledge and would therefore be dropped from the queue.

However, I was running `curl 8.8.7.5`, which would obviously result in retransmissions that I could watch in Wireshark, but the tx_dropped value remained 0.

Actually, in all the times I've run my program, I've never seen `tx_dropped` with a value other than `0`.

What situation would make `tx_dropped` increase?